# How to start two animations on two different views on API lvl 19

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a working example for animating two views with two different animations at the same time. 
But for some reason, this just doesn`t work on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19) devices.

The animations happen, but the setFillAfter is not applied and at the end, the views are returned as they were at the starting point.

Here is the code:

```
// Creating an animation set
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animationSet.setFillAfter(true);

// Creating a Scale Animation
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(
zoomPercent, newZoom, zoomPercent, newZoom, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, zoomPointX, // Pivot point of X scaling
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, zoomPointY); // Pivot point of Y scaling

// Creating a Translate animation
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, translateX,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, translateY,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);

//Adding the animations to the set
animationSet.addAnimation(anim);
animationSet.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
animationSet.setDuration(duration);

// Creating Alpha animation
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0f);
alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);    
alphaAnimation.setDuration(duration);

relativeLayout.startAnimation(animationSet); //id="@+id/relative_layout"
darkOverlay.startAnimation(alphaAnimation); //darkOverlay is DarkOverlayView extends View, can be seen below
```

The layout that I animate looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <com.example.DarkOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/dark_overlay_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion will help. So far I have tried .setFillEnabled(true) on both the sets but with no effect.
I have also tried to start the second animation after the onAnimationStart callback of the first one is called.
This had no result too.

**Update:**
I found the problem and it was that I was using [Animation.getTansformation(long currentTime, 
                Transformation outTransformation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#getTransformation(long,%20android.view.animation.Transformation)) while the animation was still running and for some reason after the animation ends the result is not applied.

Comment: Could you please post or share the test project for download for the same issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I can not share more than this snippet.

Comment: I did the same with two image views and it is working.

Comment: What version are you running your code on? If 19, can you share a snippet so I can try it too?

Comment: Yes, it is 19 and I made some changes in one of my production code for place holder values like duration, pivot point etc.  The production code I cannot share. If I will get time I will create a new project and share it on github.

Comment: I have added a layout snippet because I think if has something to do with the DarkOverlayView being a child of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135352/discussion-between-simona-stoyanova-and-anurag-singh).